# Ansible not installing latest version of Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, vagrant, virtual-machine, ansible

My Ansible script is installing Mysql version 5.4, but I need it to install 5.7.

This is the code:

```
- name: mysql | Install MySQL Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
    - mysql-server
    - mysql-client
    - python-mysqldb
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
- name: mysql | Install MySQL Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
    - mysql-server-5.7
    - mysql-client-5.7
    - python-mysqldb
```

Anyone know how to get Ansible to install Mysql 5.7?

Answer (score 3):

I would expect 5.4 is the latest version available per `apt`. Unless you're saying you can install MySQL 5.7 with `apt` manually on the command line, this is not an Ansible issue.

You can try to activate the `update_cache` option.

```
- name: mysql | Install MySQL Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt:
    pkg: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
  with_items:
    - mysql-server
    - mysql-client
    - python-mysqldb
```

Also you could try to add the [MySQL apt repository](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-repo-manual-setup) with the [`apt_repository` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_repository_module.html) before installing MySQL. Something like this:

```
- apt_repository:
    repo: 'deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ precise mysql-5.7'
    state: present
```

Comment: The update_cache idea doesn't work unfortunately. I'm trying to do the second one, but getting this error 'repo is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler ... '. Do you know where this command should be placed?

Comment: Your indentation is almost certainly off. Check that and try again.